# Respected journal uses only a single reviewer and has a high acceptance rate (>85%); could this be an acceptable practice?

Tags: peer-review, publishers

I have recently noticed a failed case of peer review at *The Astrophysical Journal* (ApJ). It is a solid journal in which researchers of astrophysics can present good science without worrying about the topic being fashionable (as opposed to, e.g., *Nature* and *Science*). The peer-reviewed [paper in question](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/812/1/8/pdf) was published in ApJ but [retracted](http://aas.org/posts/news/2015/11/astrophysical-journal-paper-retracted-plagiarism) by the journal within a week after it was reported as a case of plagiarism.

However, the issue I'd like to raise is not about plagiarism but about the review process of the journal. In the aforementioned paper, there are obvious technical errors that do not even pass a basic sanity check. I believe that had it been properly reviewed, the paper could in no way have been accepted in the first place, plagiarized or not.

(For more information, see my [comment](http://scholarlyoa.com/2015/11/20/is-this-17-year-old-korean-ph-d-student-a-plagiarist/#comment-387392) on Jeffrey Beall's blog post about the incidence of plagiarism. Moreover, my [Astronomy SE post](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/12618/does-this-black-hole-magnetohydrodynamics-equation-even-superficially-make-sense) contains some technical details. The latter was posed as a question but I'm now sure that my suspiscion---that there are blatant errors in the paper---is well-founded. I had at first shied away from the obvious conclusion just because I have no expertise in astrophysics.)

It is disturbing that the acceptance rate of the journal is very high (between 85--90%) while only a single referee participates in the review process. (ApJ seeks an additional opinion only if the acceptance decision cannot be made without one.) As the low quality of the retracted paper demonstrates, any such a single-reviewer model falls apart when a referee hastily signs off the paper.

This incident seems to show the poor review process of ApJ. Could this be justified simply on the grounds that no better practice is available in the field? Or is this worrysome even after acknowledging that academic customs greatly vary across different fields?

Comment: See https://aas.org/files/resources/aasjan2014_burton.pdf for the review practice of ApJ.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58502/journal-paper-and-conference-proceedings-note-appear-to-be-identical-is-this-pl

Comment: In the acknowledgments they claim that Kip Thorne also looked at their paper.  Presumably he didn't tell them it was wrong.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Hi David, thanks for your edit to make the title sound more natural and also for your comment. Considering the dishonesty (plagiarism) involved in the paper, I also find it doubtful that Kip Thorne really read the paper and gave comments to the authors, as they may have liked to imply in the Acknowledgments.

Comment: I find some of the statistics here eye-opening.  An acceptance rate of 85-90% is not inherently problematic, but it is surprisingly high.  Also publishing 20,000 papers per year boggles my mind: my Fermi-type calculation puts this at the same order of magnitude as all papers published in astrophysics in a given year.  So this journal sounds culturally exceptional to me.  Perhaps it functions more like a preprint server than a conventional journal: i.e., you expect to find a large portion of papers in your field there, and you expect the stuff there not to be nonsense, but that's about it.

Comment: What makes this journal a respectable one? It seems either the standards of the scientific community are very low or exceptionally high ( they send out papers so good that no reviewer can improve it).

Comment: @Greg - "_What makes this journal a respectable one_?" - There have been some good works too that it has published. e.g. G. E. Brown and H. A. Bethe, Ap. J. 423, 659 (1994). But I'm not taking sides..

Comment: @PeteL.Clark - I am curious regarding your statement "_my Fermi-type calculation puts this at the same order of magnitude as all papers published in astrophysics in a given year_". How did you arrive at that?

Comment: @TheDarkSide: Well, I hope you know that a "Fermi-type calculation" is fancy language for "a quick/lazy mixture of calculation and guesswork", but e.g. see http://arxiv.org/year/astro-ph/14.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Sorry, it's only 4,000 papers a year.  I was looking at the wrong slide in the linked pdf.  Corrected now.

Comment: '@David: Ah, that makes a lot more sense.  :) "Only" 4,000 papers then.

Comment: If there was a respectable journal with even just 50% acceptance rate, it would be flooded with "spam" submissions. Hey, this is unfinished or did not work, but let's try submitting it there anyway?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark You're partially right. There are 40-60 preprints posted to astro-ph per day (no paper in astro is not on arxiv), and there are only two journals in astrophysics (ApJ and MNRAS), so they do get a significant chunk of all papers. *However*, it is nothing like a preprint server -- the papers are generally very high quality. I should note that astro is a *much* smaller community than most appreciate -- your own university has 4 or 5 astro research faculty, compared to 30 for math. In our community, the idea of a paper being too unprestigious for our journal is alien.

Comment: It is not as if Math would be a single community, submitting to the same journal. You have logics, statistics, numerics, ... they are each their own communities, with maybe only 1 or 2 faculty at your university.

Comment: @Chris: I didn't mean that the journal does business like a preprint server -- I assume the papers get refereed -- but from a certain point of view, if half of all the astrophysics papers which appear on the arxiv appear in one journal, then that journal bears a lot in common with the arxiv, if you see what I mean.  Moreover the phenomenon that the majority of papers in a field get published in two journals is very different from what happens in other fields I know about (especially math)....

Comment: ....I also think that you may be understating the relative size of the astrophysics community.  The number of arxiv math papers in 2014 is between 2 and 3 times the number of astrophysics papers.  This means (I think) that astrophysics is much larger in size than any one subfield of mathematics.  But most subfields of mathematics have at least a dozen journals devoted to that subfield *and* the vast majority of mathematics journals are not subject specific.....

Comment: ...So e.g. as a number theorist I could plausibly submit to hundreds of journals, and the distinction in quality here is tremendous.  I am a tenured faculty member at a nationally ranked research university, and I have never published a paper in the top tier of math journals (which consists of at least five journals).  So from my perspective it is remarkable that such a large community does all its business with basically two journals.  It's not necessarily a bad thing, but it is certainly very different, and it's not really clear why abuses like the one described here don't happen more often.

Comment: Apparently, the editor of ApJ is the former advisor of Dr. Park, one of the authors... It probably is only a coincidence (Wikipedia sais 8.5% of the Koreans have this name), but his mother is called "*Park* Ok-seon"? Again, this is a *very* common name, apparently.
Oh, and Korea has a copyright problem in science: http://www.koreaherald.com/view.php?ud=20151124001042

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: The question is about the general publication practices of a very high volume journal.  I don't see the point of harping too much on one of 4000 papers the journal published that year after it has already been retracted: it does not seem very representative of the general case.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark well, that comment is rather precisely on that one article, isn't it? But as is, every single discipline seems to have a review problem (the difference is only if we acknowledge this); and more and more universities seem to offer a bonus for every article published - so there is an increasing demand to publish whatever gets through, unfortunately the wrong incentive to publish... so I am surprised and scared that ApJ has such a high acceptance rate and only one reviewer. Sounds like heaven for low-quality submitters to me. I'm used to 20% acceptance rates.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse It is indeed a conincidence that Dr. Park (the advisor of the boy) and the boy's mother have the same surname. Dr. Vishniac (ApJ editor-in-chief), being Dr. Park's former advisor, recused himself in the investigation of plagiarism. It appears that Dr. Park and Dr. Vishniac personally exchanged emails while this incident was ongoing. Dr. Park even told the media that the editor-in-chief reassured him that there is no problem. But later he conceded that Dr. Vishniac really said that conference precedings are not in general considered as a prior publication.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse In this case, however, the conclusion of the investigation was that the paper is a case of plagiarism. It is almost identical to the conference proceeding published 13 years ago, and the lead authors are different.

Comment: The main critizism in the retraction actually is that it wasn't *cited* at all, despite being the single most relevant prior work... which raises the same question again: how come the reviewer did not notice?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse You are right. I should have been more careful in what I said because it could be misinterpreted as representing the exact wording of the official retraction statement. Still, note that according to the retraction statment, not citing the 2002 publication had significant effect on the peer-review process. It implies that the 2015 paper would have been certainly rejected had the authors cited the 2002 publication.

Comment: ApJ is one of the top journals for astronomy, where having only one referee look at a paper is entirely standard practice. Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society and Astronomy and Astrophysics are two other top-tier papers that have a single referee. I know of no journal that has more than one actually.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By saying

> This incidence demonstrates the poor review process of ApJ

you are already asserting an answer to your question.  What you can say based on the facts you have presented is that **the peer review process failed in one instance**.  The document you have linked indicates that the ApJ publishes roughly 4,000 papers per year, so one failure per year would represent just **twenty-five thousandths of a percent**.  Extrapolating based on that seems wrong (and in any case, you haven't mentioned any failures of the system in previous years).

The term *acceptable* refers to agreement of a group of people.  The refereeing process of the ApJ is clearly not only "acceptable", but in fact *accepted*, as it is a leading journal in its field.

More generally, **should a high acceptance rate be a cause for concern?**  Independent of other indicators, I think the answer is **no**.  A high acceptance rate for a leading journal may be surprising to researchers from other fields.  But it seems the ApJ is mainly interested in the correctness of a paper (rather than, as you say, whether it is fashionable).  So the acceptance rate should depend on the ratio of correct and incorrect papers submitted.  Here of course "incorrect" means fundamentally incorrect and unfixable.  I don't know of any fundamental reason that there must be a large fraction of incorrect papers.

**Should the use of a single referee be a cause for concern?**  For many (including myself) this is very surprising and goes counter to familiar practices.  But the ApJ is being up-front about this, so any group that wants to change the practice could start a new journal or lobby the editors of the ApJ.  I think this question is one the astrophysics community should handle for itself.  So far, their answer seems to be "no".

Comment: @arendellean: For what it's worth, the majority of journals in my field (mathematics) use a single referee, including some very prestigious ones.

Comment: I disagree with the acceptance rate discussion. If a journal has a high reputation, it will receive a substantial amount of junk. If you had the reputation of a high acceptance rate, you would become the one place where everybody dumps their junk. I read that e.g. Science rejects 80% of articles *prior to peer review*. It's not as if every author would only submit "correct" papers - in particular not if you know a venue has a high acceptance rate. Because high reputation and acceptance rate attract low quality submissions, and you will have to either drop your quality, or your acceptance rate.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse What you don't understand about astrophysics is that it is a *small* community. Submit junk to the journal, the journal will ignore you, and then your career is over. I'm willing to bet the same phenomenon occurs in other niche fields, and that the fraction of junk submissions scales with the size of the community.

Comment: Simple correctness doesn't make a paper significant or any kind of quality. Stating that the only requirement to be published is to be formally correct is a very low scientific standard in most fields.

Comment: (Typo corrected) Thanks for your detailed answer. I think I should have toned down in the part you quoted. I, too, believe that the high acceptance rate alone isn't necessarily problematic. But in combination with the fact that they use a single referee, it sounds surprising.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark According to my mathematician friend, it may be that, in effect, arXiv eases the burden for mathematics journals. That is, almost all papers are posted on arXiv so that they can be read and assessed by experts in the field much earlier than it is actually published. Then, the journals may be able to use only a single referee without worrying about quality control. In fact, what I have said is generally true for astrophysics. (Nevertheless, this particular retracted paper has hever been posted on arXiv.)

Comment: I do not know of a single astronomy-related journal employing more than one referee per paper. I think the reason is not exactly that it's a small community, but rather that it is a very fragmented one, and for a lot of topics of current research interest, I cannot imagine there to be more than a half-handful of possible referees. This ties into what @ChrisWhite said: publish garbage and it sticks to your name.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I think the question about acceptance rate cannot be divorced from the volume of published material, which seems quite high given that this is a "niche" field according to the prior discussion.

Also, I think the original question could be entirely resolved by instituting open reviews. We would then be able to see the review which argued for acceptance of the paper in question, as well as all the other reviews. It would be straightforward to judge how well these papers are being evaluated. Furthermore, it would be easy for substandard reviews to be augmented by the community.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give an example: Advances in Colloid and Interface Science also has an unusually high acceptance rate (I've seen numbers from ~65% to ~85%), and is very reputable / high impact. It has a much lower volume, though.

You can find acceptance rates for all Elsevier journals, but it's a very round-and-about process. I really wish they would give you the same list searchable by journal names. (I'm all ears if someone knows how to find this). Here's how I've been able to find them:

- Go to the Elsevier Journal Finder: http://journalfinder.elsevier.com/
- Put words in "Title" and "Abstract" that will give you the journal you're interested in (this is tricky)
- The result is the 10 journals "most relevant for the title/abstract", with the following statistics:

  - Name and Scope (click "Scope and Information")
  - Impact factor
  - Acceptance rate
  - Average time to first editorial decision
  - Time from accept to published
  - Open access status (none/optional/mandatory)
  - Open access fee
  - Embargo time (time from published until access is free (as in, no subscription needed) )
  - License (Creative Commons etc.)